# JSON object error Android

Tags: android

I used a Web Service for Android application. The problem is there

```
jData.put("imei",MyMethods.getImeiNumber(context));    
jData.put("lat",loc.getLatitude());    
jData.put("lng",loc.getLongitude());    
jData.put("place",providerTag);
```

`providerTag` is a String object, it makes the whole JSON null. But when I put a static string like `"string"` it works fine.

Comment: What do you mean with "whole JSON is null"? Calling `jData.toString()` returns null?

Comment: no i return correct data... but then i think the problem is in my web service.. but why web service work when i put direct string like "STRING" :(

Comment: Yes problem is in my web service... i is solved now... but i wonder about these line of code in web service if(isset($_GET['jData']))
{
 //valid request to store data
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
  $jData  = stripslashes($_GET['jData']);
}else{
  $jData = $_GET['jData'];
}  it some time works and some time need to remove

Comment: so how i solved.... providerTag this String object contains a space which create problem... when jsonObject reaches on web service it becomes null due to this space... how and why? i don't know

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you can't put a string[] object into a jsonobject, you can use a hashmap instead.

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html